# The informal name for windscreen washer fluid

Tags: word-choice, informal-language

What would be the right term for *windscreen washer fluid* that e.g. gas station's personnel would use? C.f. *traffic turn indicator* would be called *blinker*. So I'm looking for an informal name used by common people.

Comment: In the US it is "windshield washer fluid." Just "washer fluid" would almost certainly suffice. One jocular name is "bug juice."

Comment: @MaxW Is there anything shorter, a single word or so? If I say *where's the fluid* or *where's the washer* - would a clerk understand without noticing anything strange?

Comment: No single word that I can think of at the moment. There are all sorts of fluids in a car - for example brake fluid. In the US a "washer" typically means a clothes washer.

Comment: @maxw I'd say a "washer" typically means a metal ring that you put around a bolt before putting on the nut. But that's the problem with asking for a single word meaning X with no context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done most of my driving in California and Washington.  I refer to the liquid in question as either "windshield wiper fluid" or "wiper fluid".  So the informal name (that I am familiar with) is "**wiper fluid**".

Answer (score 3):

For **windscreen washer fluid**, the shortest might be **washer fluid** or, to remove any ambiguity, **windshield washer fluid**.

I'm assuming since you're asking about **gas stations** and not a **petrol station** and your use of **windscreen**, that your question is AmE related and not BrE related.

Comment: No geographic preference on this one. In fact, I haven't realized that there were different names for those. I've learned English through Terminator and Die Hard, so I tend to use American terminology, often forgetting the different *flavours* and *colours* of English, hehe.

Comment: I have a jug of the stuff in my basement. I just checked the label and it says "windshield washer fluid".

Comment: I've heard the term "windscreen", but everyone I know says "windshield". Maybe this is a regionalism. I live in the Eastern US.

Comment: @Jay I think "windshield" is the common American term and "windscreen" is BrE. I've only ever heard the latter on *Top Gear*.

Comment: @Era you are correct, a jug of the stuff is often kept in the **boot** (trunk) and the reservior gets refilled under the **bonnet** (hood). **TG** not the same without Clarkson or Hamster